# Merged Columns in Python Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

How can I make this table: [image: this]

into a Pandas data frame? Can't make that Machine Column.

Comment: Can you provide detail about your question and also provide sample input & output.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that in a dataframe, as you can't have a one-level index combined with a multi-level index on the same axis.

One way to get as close as possible to what you want is to concatenate individual pandas series for the first one-level columns with a two-level dataframe for the 'machine' columns like follows:

```py
pd.concat({
    'Company name': pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c']),
    'Number of machines': pd.Series([1, 4, 2]),
    'Machines': pd.DataFrame({
        '2015-2020': pd.Series([3, 1, 0]),
        '2018-2014': pd.Series([1, 8, 3]),
        'Other': pd.Series([5, 0, 4]),
    })
}, axis=1)
```

You will still a two-level index as a result, and the first columns will have a 2nd level integer index (0, 1 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. My boss asked me to make some process in file and show it to him in excel file like i posted here. (its just example but columns have to be exactly like it)

[xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D76Q5.png)